# test for existing directory passes for directory that does not exist

Tags: directory, test

#### Action

I have set an environment variable in a user profile

```
export DATADIR=<absolute path set with `readlink -e target`>
```

#### Expected outcomes

After sourcing the profile file again, I checked that it links to the target with

```
echo ${DATADIR}; ls ${DATADIR}
```

which are a pass. If I do a test on whether

```
test -d ${DATADIR} && echo yes || echo no
```

it is an **expected pass** as well (outcome 'yes')

#### Unexpected outcomes

However, if I give another directory name that has not been defined at all, say with any gibberish name, the test

```
test -d ${HJIWEODSB} && echo yes || echo no
```

also give me a yes, that is an **unexpected pass**, since this name is no file and no directory.

#### Expected outcomes again

Actually also

```
test -d  && echo yes || echo no
```

gives yes, which makes me think that it refers to the current directory in the same way as `ls`

### Question

I have had a look at the man pages of test and to this page on [Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/test-linux-command-unix-command-4097166).
Probably I am overlooking something them.
In sum, I need a robust test for the existence of a directory.
Corrections and tips welcome.

---

Feel free to downvote of course. However, any suggestion about why this is not useful or is unclear or shows no research effort will be appreciated anyhow.

Comment: `test -d` is _true_ since `-d` is a string of non-zero length. It's the same thing as `test -n "-d"`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found an answer thanks to the writing of this post.

To get the expected outcomes do include the variable names in quotes:

```
test -d "${DATADIR}" && echo yes || echo no
```

gives yes, while

```
test -d "${GIBBERISH}" && echo yes || echo no
```

gives no.

(Meta remark: I have decided not to delete my question, for some future readers may benefit from that. Moderators please decide whether this is appropriate.)

Comment: Also note the _other_ error in your code, the `$` on the variable should not be there in `export $DATADIR=...`.  This is what gives you an empty `DATADIR` variable (you never give it a value).  Also, do you really have to `export` it?

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, it was a typo in the post and was right in the original script. Then, I am glad to take references for reading on the proper use of `export`: in my case I know that this variable should hold for the processes started by the script it defined in.

Comment: You use `export` to create an environment variable. You create an environment variable when that variable has to be inherited by child processes. In all other cases, `export` is not needed and it's enough to leave the variable as a shell variable.

Comment: @Kusalananda So in my case it is justified. Thanks for the addition